# How to get the string of binded item in a listbox programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, listbox

I have a listboxitem with a data template that have something like this:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
```

and i use this to add values to the bindings.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(New User() With {.Name= "John Crooks", .Age = 42})
```

is it possible to retrieve these data programmatically, for example. i'm trying to get the age of the selected item programmatically. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the value of the `SelectedItem` property to your data item type and then access its properties.

In C#:

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    var myItem = (MyItem)ListBox1.SelectedItem;
    var name = myItem.Name;
}
```

That should be something like this in VB:

```
Dim myItem As MyItem = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, MyItem)
Dim name As String = myItem.Name
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. :(

Comment: Then check for null first.

Comment: how am i supposed to do that? sorry.

Comment: i figured it out. Thank You SO SO MUCH!

Comment: one more thing. is it possible to update a specific item in the listbox?

Comment: Sure, just set its properties. Note that the item class should then implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that the bindings in the UI get updated.

Comment: i have another problem, but how can i check the info of a specific item in the listbox for example item no 3 and not just the selected item. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don't ask question after question in comments. Ask another regular question on StackOverflow. In this case, items can be accessed by their index, e.g. `ListBox1.Items[3]`. That is really trivial. Try to do some basic research effort on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need declare in XAML:

```
xmlns:localData="YourAssembly.dll"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=localData:YourClass}"
```